# boost unit test trouble

Tags: c++, unit-testing, boost

I am getting started with Boost Unit Tests, and I have just faced that problem:
My program just don't run, compiler tells me that `abort()` was called after `BOOST_REQUIRE(sum(5,2) == 7);` But this statement is true, and I suppose that this code must work correctly. What is the problem?

```
#define BOOST_TEST_NO_MAIN
#include <boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int sum(int x, int y) {
    return x + y;
}

int main() {
    BOOST_REQUIRE(sum(5,2) == 7);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're not really using Boost.Test properly.
The introductory example on the boost site is pretty good.
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/test/doc/html/tutorials/hello-the-testing-world.html

Comment: @KyleC, should I use BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE everywhere ?

Comment: @KyleC, then I face another problem, BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE requires to be placed outside main() , but I need to work with some objects, created in main(). What I should do to avoid this?

Comment: are you actually trying to create unit tests? The main shouldn't be needed, what you really want to do is create your logic in separate classes, and reference that logic in your unit tests to test their functionality.

Comment: @KyleC, OK. How can I test functionality of a class, if this class has only non-static methods?

Comment: You instantiate the class in the unit test itself.